# Django Is not raising a form error due to override request.user

Tags: django

I have a application that allow users to send each other messages.

The current function which I am working on ,  obtains the message id and populates the message object in a form . Its like a draft message then it would allow the user to edit the message form and send it.

I have a User model called person and it has an attribute called inbox . This attribute determines if a user would like his inbox activated or deactivated

The issue , I am having trouble with is . My form called draftform would not raise an error if the user deactivated his inbox. but It does raise an error if the field is missing or user does not exist

I am assuming their is a problem in the connection with how I pass request.user in forms and in views.py . May someone please help me

views.py

```
class Person(models.Model):

    inbox = (
        ('A', 'Activate'),
        ('D', 'Deactivate'),
        ('F', 'Permit To Friends Only'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    inbox = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=inbox ,default='A')



class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views

```
@login_required
def ReadDraft(request,id):
    try:
        messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id,recipient=request.user) 
    except Message.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Display'))
    thread = Thread.objects.get(message=messages)
    initial = {}
    initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})
    draft = DraftForm(request,instance=messages,initial=initial)
    thread = ThreadForm(instance=thread)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method =='POST':
        id = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
        form = ThreadForm(request.POST)
        forms = DraftForm(request,request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and forms.is_valid():

            m = Message.objects.get(pk=id,)
            recipient = forms.cleaned_data['recipient']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            body = forms.cleaned_data['body']
            person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

            m.user =request.user
            m.recipient = recipient
            m.body = body
            m.draft = False
            m.sentmessage = True
            m.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
        else:
            ctx = {'DraftForm': forms, 'ThreadForm': form,'person':person}
            return render(request, 'create.html', ctx)


    return render(request,'create.html',{'DraftForm':draft,'ThreadForm':thread,'person':person})
```

forms.py

```
class DraftForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipient = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=51)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True,max_length=51)
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())       

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(DraftForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_recipient(self):

            recipient = self.cleaned_data['recipient']
            person = Person.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            if person.inbox == "D":
                    raise forms.ValidationError("You have deactivated your inbox , Please enable it at profile settings")
            if recipient:

                try:
                    recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("This username does not exist")
                return recipient



    class Meta:
        model = Message 
        fields = ('body',)  

    def clean_recipient(self):
        recipient = self.cleaned_data['recipient']

        try:
            recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username does not exist")
        return recipient


class ThreadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thread 
        fields = ('subject',)
```

create.html

```
{% if DraftForm and ThreadForm %}

<form method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}

    {{DraftForm.recipient}}
{{ThreadForm.subject}}
        {{DraftForm.body}}
    {{DraftForm.hidden_field}}
    <input type = "submit" value= "send" class="save" id="send"  />


</form>

{% endif %}



{{ThreadForm.subject.errors}}
{{DraftForm.recipient.errors}}
{{DraftForm.body.errors}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tags in the template to handle that. For example:

```
{% if ThreadForm.errors %}
  <your raising message here>    
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What the downside to using {{ThreadForm.subject.errors}}? when they both do raise each error?

Comment: using it this way looks like you are referencing the attribute of ThreadForm to the template like a simple variable,